# Adding hyperlinks to index array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add a link in the description of an index array in javascript? My code is below, thanks. I tried using push method, but I think I had a conflict with the showpic function. I really don't know, so I would appreciate any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mypic = new Array();
    mypic[0] = ["images/Lg_image1.jpg", "Large image 1 description."] //I want to add an HTML  link to a website at the end of this array
    mypic[1] = ["images/Lg_image2.jpg", "Large image 2 description."] //I want to add an HTML link to a website at the end of this array



    function showpic2(n) {
        document.getElementById("mainpic2").src = mypic[n][0]
        document.getElementById("mycaption2").innerHTML = mypic[n][1]
        count = n
    }

    count = 0;

    function next() {
        count++
        if (count == mypic2.length) {
            count = 0
        }
        document.getElementById("mainpic2").src = mypic2[count][0]
        document.getElementById("mycaption2").innerHTML = mypic2[count][1]
    }

    function prev() {
        count--
        if (count < 0) {
            count = mypic2.length - 1
        }
        document.getElementById("mainpic2").src = mypic2[count][0]
        document.getElementById("mycaption2").innerHTML = mypic2[count][1]
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="menu1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="large"> <img src="images/Lg_image1.jpg" class="mainpic2" id="mainpic2"> </div>
  <div id="thumbs2"> <a href="javascript:showpic2(0)"><img src="images/sm_image1.jpg" alt="image1"/></a> <a href="javascript:showpic2(1)"><img src="images/sm_image2.jpg" alt="image2"/></a> </div>
  <div id="mycaption2">Large image default description. </div>
  <div id="logohome"> <img src="images/#.png" alt="" /> </div>
  <div id="homebox"> <img src="images/homebox1.png" alt="" /> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `mypic2`? Look for possible typos... Also check the console for errors

Comment: Did I miss something and the ; become optional in JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mypic = [];
    mypic.push({address:"images/Lg_image1.jpg", desc: "Large image 1 description."});




    function showpic2(n) {
        document.getElementById("mainpic2").src = mypic['address']
        document.getElementById("mycaption2").innerHTML = mypic['desc']
        count = n
    }


</script>
```

something like this

Comment: Kangoroo, I did the following, but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what problems you had with `.push()` but this should work:

```
mypic[0].push("<a href='link.html'>I am a link</a>");
```

And of course the same can be done with `mypic[1]`.

Comment: David, Thanks for the reply. I did this: mypic[0].push("<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>link</a>"["images/Lg_image1.jpg","Large image 1 description."]);